# Expanding a DataFrame from a col full of Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

I have a big data frame, where one of the columns (event_properties) has one dictionary per row (with different keys).

I would like to expand the data frame with one col per unique key with a None value in the rows where that particular key does not exist.

I tried something like:

```
p = df.copy()
y = df.event_properties.values.tolist()
event_properties = pd.DataFrame(y)
df = pd.concat([p, event_properties])
```

But there is something wrong with this code because if I do:

```
df[['event_properties', 'author']][:2]
```

I visualize something like:

```
event_properties    author
120 {'author': 'Larsson, Stieg', 'product_id': '6a...   NaN
128 {'author': 'Larsson, Stieg', 'product_id': '40...   NaN
```

and this is clearly wrong.

I am quite annoyed by this totally unexpected behaviour, can anyone clarify why is this happening and how should I fix it?

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of your dataframe

Comment: you may have an index mismatch, try `event_properties = pd.DataFrame(y, index=p.index)` and/or also you should specify `axis=1` in the concat?